# Checking whether a picture fits the photo requirements for a US visa

Tags: images

I am looking for an offline program that can check whether a picture fits the photo [requirements](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/photos.html) for a US visa/passport. Ideally, free, Windows, and can process several pictures at once.

[image]

Comment: Must be able to work offline?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes.